# Cruisecontrol:how to view the build results

Tags: cruisecontrol

when thte build is completed i received an email with the link to see the results.
Is it possible to configure the config.xml file to see the result in format text directly within the email received? Which is the way to do it?
For do it, is it necessary to merge the log???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `ccnet.exe.config` (NOT `ccnet.config`) and look for this section:

```
<xslFiles>
  <file name="xsl\header.xsl" />
  <file name="xsl\modifications.xsl" />
  <file name="xsl\msbuild2ccnet.xsl" /> <!-- This is our build results transform-->
</xslFiles>
```

add the XSL transform for your build results (if your not sure which, look for the `<xslFileNames>` section in your `dashboard.config`)

Comment: Not really sure if OP refers to CruiseControl.NET or `plain` CruiseControl.

Answer (score 0):

You might either edit the email publisher, or write your own. You can easily send emails from console, attached the formatted build resoults.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the mails sent is controlled by XSL(T) files, see [documentation for <htmlemail>](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#htmlemail).

You can find the original ones at: `$CCDIR/webapps/cruisecontrol/xsl`. In our setup we just copied the files to some other directory, tweaked them to our needs and pointed the new directory with the `xsldir` attribute of `<htmlemail>`.